# Is the Null Space of an linear operator the same with the Null Space of its associated hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let A be a bounded linear operator on $H$ where $H$ is a (not necessary I think, but in my case separable) Hilbert space. Then, the question: is its null space the same as the null space of the hermitian operator $A^*A$ ?

The operator  $A^*$ is its "adjoint", defined regarding the inner product on $H$: $\langle Au,v\rangle = \langle u,A^*v\rangle$ for every pair $u,v\in H$, and the null space of $A$ is the set of vectors $u$ in $H$ verifying $Au = 0$.

I did not find a written proof, may be because it should be trivial.
 So, here are my arguments: if $u \neq 0$ and $Au = 0$, then  $A^*Au = 0$, and first inclusion between null spaces follows. Reverse, if   $A^*Au = 0$, then for every $v$, $\langle A^*Au,v\rangle = 0;$ or, $\langle Au,Av\rangle = 0$, that for $v=u$ becomes: $\Vert Au \Vert^{2} = 0$. It follows that $Au = 0$, proving the reverse inclusion between null subspaces of $A$ and $A^*A$.

Am I right? If so, we could go further, proving in the same manner that the null space of $A$ is the same with the null space of $(A^*A)^{1/2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the standard argument. The fact that $\ker (A^*A)^{1/2}=\ker A$ is used in the polar decomposition $$ A=V(A^*A)^{1/2}$$ to argue that the partial isometry $V$ maps the closure of the range of $A^*$ onto the closure of the range of $A$,  because 
$$
\overline{\text{ran}\,A^*}=(\ker A)^\perp=(\ker (A^*A)^{1/2})^\perp=\text{ran}\,(A^*A)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you PhoemueX and Martin, I really appreciate your prompt answers.

Comment: On the right-hand side of your last equation, didn't you forget to build the closure of the range?